# Digital Clock Manager on FPGA - Boundary Problem

Tags: fpga, vivado

I am working on BASYS3 and using Vivado. I have a 3 MHz signal and I have to make it close to 190 MHz. BASYS3 can increase the frequency by 64 times; however my problem is that BASYS3 takes at least 10 MHz as an DCM input frequency, so 3 is not enough. Is there anything that I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Change your 3mHz signal source to 10mHz? Use a simple PLL up converter to multiply your 3mHz by a factor of 4 to 12MHz?

Comment: Thank you but PLL takes at least 19mHz as an input however i have 3mHz. So it cannot solve my problem.

Comment: Can you cascade two PLLs?

Answer (score 1):

When you can't meet the requirements of the internal PLLs, you must use external circuitry. At a minimum, you need an external VCO or VCXO, and a filter to drive it. The divider(s) and phase detector can be implemented as logic inside the FPGA.